# delay time to activate uislider inside uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, uislider, uitableview

I added a UISlider to my dynamic table view cell prototype using storyboard. It is hard to activate the slider (just touching down and dragging the knob doesn’t activate it, you have to press down on the knob and hold it for a bit to receive the trigger and begin sliding).

This makes it hard to control the slider.

Note: There are 6 other views in the same cell (image view, labels, blank views with background color) and a uiview with white background behind the slider. I have disabled many view’s userInteraction property.

I have the slider configured to store values into array so I am aware of the dequeue cell issue with content views inside of a cell.

Comment: Have you tried setting "delaysContentTouches" to "NO"?

Comment: Well it is not due to dequeue thing. If the cell is visible why would dequeue effect it unless you reload it everytime the slider value change. I suspect that you do some intense calculation when the slider change. That is why it does not work as you expect.

Comment: I solved this issue, Seems like there is a bug in iOS 7/8 when the navigation controller hides on swipe is enabled, the UI Sliders inside of UITableViewCells are not responsive

Answer (score 1):

Setting .delaysContentTouches on the table helped in my case.

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.delaysContentTouches = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

There is bug on iOS8 and last version of Xcode 6 where if the navigation controller is switched to hide on scroll then uisliders inside of table view cell inside the root view controllers don’t work correctly